# Applying DependencyResolutionManagement configuration from a java gradle plugin to define a Version Catalog

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, gradle-plugin

I am trying to develop a grade plugin in java to configure version catalogs. The plugin can configure a version catalog in one of two ways.

1. Add a file to `libs.versions.toml` to the dependent projects `gradle` folder.
2. Apply a version catalog as part of the plugin by configuring it something like this. Assume `libs.versions.toml` file is available as part of the plugin source.

`toml` file I defined.

```
[versions]
groovy = "3.0.5"
checkstyle = "8.37"

[libraries]
groovy-core = { module = "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy", version.ref = "groovy" }
groovy-json = { module = "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json", version.ref = "groovy" }
groovy-nio = { module = "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio", version.ref = "groovy" }
commons-lang3 = { group = "org.apache.commons", name = "commons-lang3", version = { strictly = "[3.8, 4.0[", prefer="3.9" } }

[bundles]
groovy = ["groovy-core", "groovy-json", "groovy-nio"]

[plugins]
jmh = { id = "me.champeau.jmh", version = "0.6.5" }
```

Plugin

```
public class SettingsSupportPlugin implements Plugin<Settings> {
  @Override
  public void apply(@Nonnull Settings settings) {
    configureDependencyResolution(settings);
  }

  private void configureDependencyResolution(Settings settings) {
    copyFileFromJar("libs.versions.toml", "build/libs.versions.toml");
    settings.getGradle().rootProject((rootProject) -> {
      FileCollection tomlFile = rootProject.files("build/libs.versions.toml");
      settings.dependencyResolutionManagement(
          dependencyResolutionManagement -> dependencyResolutionManagement.versionCatalogs(
              versionCatalogContainer -> versionCatalogContainer.register("libs",
                  versionCatalogBuilder -> versionCatalogBuilder.from(tomlFile))));
    });
  }
}
```

After publishing the plugin, and applying it in dependent projects `settings.gradle` file. when I try to access one of the dependency using `implementation libs.groovy.core`  I run into the issue

```
> Could not get unknown property 'libs' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My initial guess was the `libs` version catalog is not created. So, I added a `libs.versions.toml` file in `gradle` directory of the dependent project, along with applying the above plugin (option 1+ 2). This gives me an error

```
Cannot add a VersionCatalogBuilder with name 'libs' as a VersionCatalogBuilder with that name already exists.
```

This shows the `version catalog` with the name `libs` is being created by the `plugin` but somehow I am not able to reference it in my dependent project. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any thoughts?